# Azure Logic App - Return email contents as JSON

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm a beginner with Azure and want to be able to have a Logic App to read the contents of an email and output it in JSON such as:

```
  {
    "from": "Azure@Microsoft.co.uk",
    "subject": "Azure Exception - A task was canceled.",
    "body": "An exception has occurred in an Azure function"
  }
```

The logic app is very basic, I have a 'when an email is received trigger' leading then to my Function App in which i am passing the Email Body as the request body. I am currently getting the http body request stuff back from the logic app such as:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style>
<!--
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math"}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri}
```

This is not what I want as the main bit of the email that I want is at the bottom as html.

In my function app I am doing the following, taking the req and

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string emailBodyContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult(emailBodyContent);
        }
```

I'm not really sure how this works but I'm returning the `req.Body`.

I am assuming that it might be something to do with the below? As we could do from: Email From, Subject: header

[image: ![enter image description here]

Any guidelines or answers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding that you would like to extract the mail body (plain text) rather than having the complete html text.

By default, in the logic app - the email body received is HTML content. To Extract the text content you can use the [Content Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/) connector.

[image]

**Output :**
[image]

**Alternative :**

You could use the `Body Preview` - if the body is smaller - the body preview will have the plain text of the body - which will directly meet your requirement.

**[image: strong text]**

### **Update**

To create JSON output you could make use of the [Compose Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action)

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks man that worked for me - do you know how we then can turn this into JSON or reference it in c#? I want to do some work on it once it's been passed in so would be helpful if its in a json structure like that at the top of my question. Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help. Updated my answer to for building a JSON structure

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it cheeky to ask a final question? How could I then pass this to a function app? Cheers

Comment: Definitely Not ! Happy to Help :) ... the `output` of the Compose action can be passed as the `Request body` of the azure function connector. At the azure function you should have provision to read the request body that triggered the function

Comment: Amazing! Thanks mate, take care